# how to give super permission to (root) user in MYSQL, despite there being no super user?

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I'm using MYSQL 8.0.25, running on WAMP server.

By mistake I changed user `root`'s privilege by unchecked (insert) privilege and pressed (go), so the changes are assigned.

The problems are:

- the super user (root) can't insert, see databases, create or do anything.
- there is not another super user to give super permissions to (root) again or create super user like root
- I can't create super user or return super permissions to (root) because there is no super user

I want to return all permissions to root again. What should I do?

[image]

could you help me

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html Use generic method, and add complete permissions list instead of ALTER USER.

Comment: please explain how

Answer (score 0):

[MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual  /  ...  /  How to Reset the Root Password](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html)

Perform generic operation described in "B.3.3.2.3 Resetting the Root Password: Generic Instructions". Instead of `ALTER USER ...` execute the next statements:

```sql
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, RELOAD, SHUTDOWN, PROCESS, FILE, 
      REFERENCES, INDEX, ALTER, SHOW DATABASES, SUPER, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, 
      LOCK TABLES, EXECUTE, REPLICATION SLAVE, REPLICATION CLIENT, CREATE VIEW, 
      SHOW VIEW, CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE, CREATE USER, EVENT, TRIGGER, 
      CREATE TABLESPACE, CREATE ROLE, DROP ROLE 
ON *.* TO `root`@`localhost` WITH GRANT OPTION;

GRANT APPLICATION_PASSWORD_ADMIN,AUDIT_ADMIN,BACKUP_ADMIN,BINLOG_ADMIN,
      BINLOG_ENCRYPTION_ADMIN,CLONE_ADMIN,CONNECTION_ADMIN,ENCRYPTION_KEY_ADMIN,
      FLUSH_OPTIMIZER_COSTS,FLUSH_STATUS,FLUSH_TABLES,FLUSH_USER_RESOURCES,
      GROUP_REPLICATION_ADMIN,INNODB_REDO_LOG_ARCHIVE,INNODB_REDO_LOG_ENABLE,
      PERSIST_RO_VARIABLES_ADMIN,REPLICATION_APPLIER,REPLICATION_SLAVE_ADMIN,
      RESOURCE_GROUP_ADMIN,RESOURCE_GROUP_USER,ROLE_ADMIN,SERVICE_CONNECTION_ADMIN,
      SET_USER_ID,SHOW_ROUTINE,SYSTEM_USER,SYSTEM_VARIABLES_ADMIN,
      TABLE_ENCRYPTION_ADMIN,XA_RECOVER_ADMIN 
ON *.* TO `root`@`localhost` WITH GRANT OPTION;

GRANT PROXY ON ''@'' TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Comment: #1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: i did it but still access denied